# Stereo to mono wave interpolation in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, wave

I'm trying to open a stereo stream and convert it to mono, using the [wave module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/wave.html) in python.
So far I was able to write a single (left or right) channel from a 16bit stereo little endian file:

```
LEFT, RIGHT = 0, 1
def mono_single(cont, chan=LEFT):
    a = iter(cont)
    mono_cont = ''
    if chan:
        a.next(); a.next()
    while True:
        try:                          
            mono_cont += a.next() + a.next()
            a.next(); a.next()
        except StopIteration:
            return mono_cont

stereo = wave.open('stereofile.wav', 'rb')
mono = wave.open('monofile.wav', 'wb')
mono.setparams(stereo.getparams())
mono.setnchannels(1)
mono.writeframes(mono_single(stereo.readframes(stereo.getnframes())))
mono.close()
```

This works as expected. The problem comes when I try to downmix the two stereo channels to a single mono channel.
I thought that a simple average between left and right would have been enough, and this is what I tried so far:

```
def mono_mix(cont):
    a = iter(cont)
    mono_cont = ''
    while True:
        try:
            left = ord(a.next()) + (ord(a.next()) << 8)
            right = ord(a.next()) + (ord(a.next()) << 8)
            value = (left + right) / 2
            mono_cont += chr(value & 255) + chr(value >> 8)
        except StopIteration:
            return mono_cont

stereo = wave.open('stereofile.wav', 'rb')
mono = wave.open('monofile.wav', 'wb')
mono.setparams(stereo.getparams())
mono.setnchannels(1)
mono.writeframes(mono_mix(stereo.readframes(stereo.getnframes())))
mono.close()
```

What I get from this is a "crackled" version of the source.
I tried different combinations (I might have misunderstood the whole endianness thing), but with no luck so far.

Answer (score 2):

Are you open to using external libraries?
if yes, you can do this easily with [pydub](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub) very few lines as follows,

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
mysound = AudioSegment.from_wav("/input_path/infile.wav")
mysound = mysound.set_channels(1)
mysound.export("/output_path/outfile.wav", format="wav")
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize pydub was able to do that. In fact, it looks like it's using the audioop module, which I wasn't aware of, so I think I'll just check its code and write my own function (I'd prefer to avoid the use of pydub since I'd need it only for this case).

Answer (score 2):

Turns out like I didn't know about the audioop built-in module (thanks to [Anil_M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5936628/anil-m)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43056200/2001654). Also, I was wrong on both converting the stereo format **and** writing (I should have used struct).

This makes everything absolutely easier:

```
stereo = wave.open('stereofile.wav', 'rb')
mono = wave.open('monofile.wav', 'wb')
mono.setparams(stereo.getparams())
mono.setnchannels(1)
mono.writeframes(audioop.tomono(stereo.readframes(float('inf')), stereo.getsampwidth(), 1, 1))
mono.close()
```

Then you can select a single channel by modifying the latest 2 parameters (`1, 0` for left, `0, 1` for right) or even using `1.414` for equal power instead of equal amplitude

Comment: Genius. Thank you so much. Would using a tempfile be possible here? I need to convert stereo to mono as Google STT API doesnt accept stereo. I would rather not write to disk. Using wave.open seems to require actual files on disk.