# What is the correct algorithm for converting a stereo .wav file into a mono .wav file?

Tags: python, audio, wav

I did some research and found out that a simple averaging over two channels is ineffective and basically outputs poor quality file.
There should be some sort of a normalization, but I'm not completely sure about it.
Basic python modules like `wave` or `audioop` don't seem to be doing the job.

What would you recommend for such a use-case? Any links or suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Seems to me that you could find a hint here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43056088/stereo-to-mono-wave-interpolation-in-python

Comment: this walks through how the channels are interleaved https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49764773/how-is-audio-data-stored-in-raw-pcm-format/49837704#49837704